# Error on installing @progress dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, telerik

I have been trying to install `@progress` dependencies but it seems as Telerik doesn't let free trial account member to install any of the dependencies.

I went on to their site http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/ and followed the steps for the installation. But after logging in with `npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress` as I try to run `npm view @progress/kendo-angular-grid versions` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "view" "@progress/kendo-angular-gr
id" "versions"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
npm ERR! <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
npm ERR! <head>
npm ERR! <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
npm ERR! <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
npm ERR! <style type="text/css">
npm ERR! <!--
npm ERR! body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
npm ERR! fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
npm ERR! h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
npm ERR! h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
npm ERR! h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
npm ERR! #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
npm ERR! background-color:#555555;}
npm ERR! #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
npm ERR! .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
npm ERR! -->
npm ERR! </style>
npm ERR! </head>
npm ERR! <body>
npm ERR! <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
npm ERR! <div id="content">
npm ERR!  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
npm ERR!   <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
npm ERR!   <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
npm ERR!  </fieldset></div>
npm ERR! </div>
npm ERR! </body>
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Do I need to be a premium member in order to install those dependencies for my project or is this error getting spawned because of something else?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik let free trial account member to install the dependencies for 30 days. Go inside your project folder and reinstall npm `npm install`.

Or you can try to install npm specifically.

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-grid @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns @progress/kendo-angular-inputs @progress/kendo-data-query @progress/kendo-angular-intl @progress/kendo-angular-l10n
```